# Update/Create table from select with changes in the column values in Oracle 11g (speed up)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

At the job we have an update script for some Oracle 11g database that takes around 20 hours, and some of the most demanding queries are updates where we change some values, something like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET
    column1 = DECODE(table1.column1,null,null,'no info','no info','default value'),
    column2 = DECODE(table1.column2,null,null,'no info','no info','another default value'),
    column3 = 'default value';
```

And like this, we have many updates. The problem is that the tables have around 10 millions of rows. We also have some updates where some columns are going to have a default value but they are nullable (I know if they have the not null and a default constrains then the add of such columns is almost immediate because the values are in a catalog), and then the update or add of such columns is costing a lot of time.

My approach is to recreate the table (as TOM said in https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330 ). But I have no idea on how to retrive some columns from the original table, that are going to remain the same and also other that are going to change to a default value (and before the update such column had a sensible info), this because we need to keep some info private.

So, my approach is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_tmp PARALLEL NOLOGGING
    AS (select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table1);

ALTER TABLE table1_tmp ADD ( col5 VARCHAR(10) default('some info') NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE table1_tmp ADD ( col6 VARCHAR(10) default('some info') NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE table1_tmp ADD ( col7 VARCHAR(10);
ALTER TABLE table1_tmp ADD ( col8 VARCHAR(10);
MERGE INTO table1_tmp tt
    USING table1 t
    ON (t.col1 = tt.col1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        tt.col7 = 'some defaul value that may be null',
        tt.col7 = 'some value that may be null';
```

I also have tried to create the nullable values as not null to do it fast, and worked, the problem is when I return the columns to null, then that operation takes too much time. The last code ended up consuming also a great amount of time (more tha one hour in the merge).

Hope have an idea on how to improve performance in stuff like this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updating all the rows of a 10-million row table is going to take some time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using NVL while joining in merge:

```sql
MERGE INTO table1_tmp tt
    USING table1 t
    ON (nlv(t.col1,'-3') = nvl(tt.col1,'-3'))
WHEN MATCHED THEN ....
```

If you don't want update null values you can also do like this:

```sql
MERGE INTO table1_tmp tt
    USING table1 t
    ON (nlv(t.col1,'-3') = nvl(tt.col1,'-2'))
WHEN MATCHED THEN .....
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I finished creating a temp table with data from the original table, and while doing the create, inserting the default values and decodes and any other stuff, like if I wanted to set something to NULL, I did the cast. Something like:

```
    CREATE TABLE table1_tmp AS (
        column1 default "default message",
        column2, --This column with no change at all
        column3, --This will take the value from the decode below 
     ) AS SELECT 
        "default message" column1,
        column2 --This column with no change at all,
        decode(column3, "Something", NULL, "A", "B") column3,
     FROM table1;
```

That is how I solved the problem. The time for coping a 23 million row's table was about 3 to 5 minutes, while updating used to take hours. Now just need to set privileges, constraints, indexes, comment, and that's it, but that stuff just takes seconds.

Thanks for the answer @thehazal  could not check your approach, but sounds interesting.